# Create android bitmap with pixels buffer efficiently?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

I have rgba8888 buffer in the native code and I have to return Bitmap instance back to java side. Now I'm invoking callbacks that creates Bitmap object in java-side and returns it back to the native side, use `setPixels` and return back to java side.

It seems that creating android Bitmap in java-side allocates memory which is not needed as I already have rgba buffer. How can I avoid it?

Comment: bmpBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(src)-May be this can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an android.graphics.Bitmap from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677092/creating-an-android-graphics-bitmap-from-c)

Comment: in the ink above it's still created by java-side classes which are invoked from native side which is completely weird